# Why is there no multipleDefine error in a layer file?

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd, js-amd

Reading much about module loading, I learned, that a module has to be defined in a single JavaScript file.
This rule is broken in the dojo layer file (http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.9.0/dojo.js.uncompressed.js). 
I thought that the file name is part of the module identifier, so I do not understand how the modules are resolved in this layer file and why there is no "multipleDefine" error ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the contents of a built layer file, you will see that it has been replaced with a call to `require` to populate the loader’s internal cache with many modules at once, looking something like this:

```js
require({
  cache: {
    'module/A': function(){
      // contents of module A
    },
    'module/B': function(){
      // contents of module B
    },
    // etc
  }
});
```

It is no longer a standard AMD module, which means:

1. it will not work if you try to use it with a loader other than the Dojo loader, and
2. you can have multiple modules defined in one file.

Incidentally, this process is the reason why you can define global variables inside a module that work fine pre-build but break after a build (all of the module code is now inside a new function with a new lexical scope).